# Hola, quisiera si alguien me pudiera explicar o guiar para el problema 10354 de OnlineJudge

Tags: python

Lo que sucede es que ya tengo un algoritmo en el cual calculo las distancias de la oficina del jefe a todos los demás, de la casa del jefe a todos los demás, esto mediante Dijkstra es una forma eficiente, luego al tener esas distancias saco los predecesores de ambos y luego los uno, como para tener el camino que recorrieron, y evaluó desde la casa del trabajador hasta el mercado exceptuando esos nodos marcados, me dan demasiados casos pero hay otros que no y no se exactamente que no estoy tomando en cuenta

##este es el codigo que tengo actualmente

```
from sys import stdin
from heapq import heappush, heappop

INF = float('inf')

def dijkstra(G, s, nodosExep=set()):
    dist = [ INF ] * len(G)
    dist[s] = 0
    pred = [-1] * len(G)
    pqueue = list()
    heappush(pqueue, (dist[s], s))

    while pqueue:
        du, u = heappop(pqueue)
        if dist[u] == du:
            for v, duv in G[u]:
                if u not in nodosExep and v not in nodosExep and du + duv < dist[v]:
                    dist[v] = du + duv
                    pred[v] = u
                    heappush(pqueue, (dist[v], v))
    
    return dist, pred

def obtenerCamino(pred, destino):
    if destino == -1:
        return []
    return obtenerCamino(pred, pred[destino]) + [destino]

def lecturaDatos():
    datos = list(map(int, stdin.readline().split()))
    while datos:
        P, R, BH, OF, YH, M = datos
        G = [[] for _ in range(P)]
        for _ in range(R):
            u, v, peso = map(int, stdin.readline().split())
            G[u-1].append((v-1, peso))
            G[v-1].append((u-1, peso))
        
        _, predHome = dijkstra(G, BH-1)
        _, predOfice = dijkstra(G, OF-1)
        caminoCasa= obtenerCamino(predHome, OF-1)
        caminoOficina = obtenerCamino(predOfice, BH-1)

        nodosExep = caminoOficina + caminoCasa
        distanciaTrabajador, _ = dijkstra(G,YH-1,nodosExep)
        
        if distanciaTrabajador[M-1] == float("inf") or distanciaTrabajador[M-1] == 0:
            print("MISSION IMPOSSIBLE.")
        else: 
            print(distanciaTrabajador[M-1])

        datos = list(map(int, stdin.readline().split()))

def main():
    lecturaDatos()  
main()
```